# Issues with folder scanning script

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to create a python script that will scan a folder. If it finds a file then it will run a command. After it has run the command it will remove the file and start over.

Below is a basic of what I have. I apologize I am quite new to scripting.

```
def func():
    for file in folder:
         while True:
              if file:
                  os.popen(*command*)
                  time.sleep(750)
                  os.remove(*file path/file*)

              else:
                  time.sleep(5)
                  return func()
```

It starts off fine then breaks after it removes the file. Thanks for any help in advanced!

Comment: *How* does it break?

Comment: After your else statement you didn't finish of time.sleep with parenthesis. That will probably not do what you meant it to.

Comment: If there are files in the folder it runs the command then it breaks once you remove file. It acts like it is still using the same file information even though it should have ended that iteration and started over. If you start the script without a file in there it just sits there and does nothing.  As far as the time.sleep call, it is correct in the script. I forgot to add it here properly.

Comment: What attempts have you made to debug this yourself? Simply printing `file` in your loop would make it quite obvious what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the infinite loop (`while True`):

```
def func():
    for file in folder:

          if file:
              os.popen(*command*)
              time.sleep(750)
              os.remove(*file path/file*)

          else:
              time.sleep(5)
              return func()
```